# temp-queue not created on activemq broker

Tags: rest, jms, activemq-classic, apache-servicemix

I'm testing out a configuration of two servicemix servers and an activemq broker.
My scenario is one servicemix acts as an incoming request mediator/router and receives REST calls. These REST calls are then routed via JMS to a service residing on the other servicemix app.

Blueprint Config on server A

```
<jaxrs:server id="myRestService" address="/webservice">
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
            <ref component-id="myRestSvc"/>
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    </jaxrs:server>

    <bean id="myRestSvc" class="com.mycompany.jaxrs.MyRequestServiceJaxrs" />

    <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
        <route>
            <from uri="cxfrs://bean:myRestService" />
            <to uri="jms://queue:myserviceq" />
        </route>
    </camelContext>
```

I can post to the REST handler on server A. The message is receive and converted to JMS and is queued on the broker on Server B.  The consumer on server C successfully gets and processes the message. However the reply always fails with:

```
Caused by: javax.jms.InvalidDestinationException: Cannot publish to a deleted Destination: temp-queue://ID:mac-mwendling-49896-1384912338253-84:7:1
```

And Server A just eventually times out with this message:

```
org.apache.camel.ExchangeTimedOutException: The OUT message was not received within: 20000 millis due reply message with correlationID: Camel-ID-mac-mwendling-49895-1384912333899-22-7 not received.
```

It seems as if the the temp-queue is never created on the Broker.

I'm using Servicemix 4.5.2 and ActiveMq 5.8.0 and I'm currently testing with all three servers running on the same machine.

Also, I tried using a Shared replyTo queue and the reply does get back to the broker but the initial requestor does not consume it.

How do I get this to work?

Comment: Are you sure there is no error on the consumer side (server C) of the queue `myserviceq`, because when it happens, it will never answering through a temporary queue.